Syntax Error in PostgresSQL When import pool into another file and run query
I'm trying to make connection with PostgreSQL and export it. When I import the pool into other file and run a query it throws the error: syntax error at end of input
postgre.js
const config = require("../config/config");
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg")

const pool = new Pool({
    host     : config.HOST,
    port     : config.PORT, // default port for mysql is 3306 
    user     : config.USER,
    password : config.PASSWORD,
    database : config.DB,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
});

pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
    console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack);
});


async function testConnect() {
    console.log('Before connect');
    const client = await pool.connect();
    console.log('Database Connected!');
    // client.release();
}

async function testSmallQuery() {
    console.log('Before small query');
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    const result = await pool.query(sql);
    console.log('Small query returned %s rows', result.rows.length);
    // pool.end();
}

async function connect() {
    await testConnect();
    await testSmallQuery();
}

connect();

module.exports = pool;

Above textConnect and testSmallQuery works and return me 0 rows
user.js
const pool = require("./postgres")

    async getUserById(req, res, next) {
                try {
                    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                    const result = await pool.query(sql);
                    pool.end();
                    return res.status(200).json(result.rows);
                } catch (error) { 
                    console.log(error);
                }
            } 

This time it throws error


After trying and struggling with different approaches. I came to know that pool.end(); causing this issue.
I just removed the pool.end() and it worked;
 async getUserById(req, res, next) {
        try {
             const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
             const result = await pool.query(sql);
             pool.end(); //remove this line
             return res.status(200).json(result.rows);
        } catch (error) { 
           console.log(error);
        }
     } 

